# Are the Akinya black?

Tags: alastair-reynolds, poseidons-children

I started reading ‘Blue remembered Earth’, and from all the details given about Geoffrey and the Akinya (the household is in Tanzania, their native tongue is Swahili, besides the surname itself) I pictured them to be black, but I don’t know if this is detailed later on in the book.

Comment: I read the entire trilogy start to finish assuming they looked typical native African / Swahili. I can't think of any references of their skin colour without skimming through the books, but I'm 100% certain any reference to them being white / Caucasian looking would stand out in my memory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's pretty safe to assume the entire Akinya family / clan look exactly as you'd expect a family from Tansania speaking Swahili would look unless the author suggests otherwise.

I have Poseidons Wake (the third book of that trilogy) as an ebook here, and almost all references to the word "skin" about about elephant skin.

The one quote I found on human skin, without spoiling any plot:

> Their faces and skin tones showed a variety of ethnicities, and there were some among them who had the sleek hairless features of the merfolk, but it was hard to be certain

Suggests in the future Alastair writes about people don't get labeled as either black or white due to generations of ethnicities mingling.